# How to disable scientific notations in logarithmic chart type

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need to disable scientific notation while using logarithmic chart type. My scales is like this

```
scales: {
    xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            maxRotation: 0
        },
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: 'Hours'
        }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
        type: 'logarithmic',
        ticks: {
            min: 0, //minimum tick
            max: 0.2, //maximum tick
            callback: function (value, index, values) { // for some reason worked few times and then no more
                return Number(value.toString());
            }
        },
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            labelString: ''
        }
    }]
}
```

And chart like this

```
CHART = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: datesLabel, // x axis, e.x 01,02,03...
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: "rgb(67 181 129 / 0.5)",
                borderColor: "rgb(67 181 129)",
                data: chart_vals,
                label: par.name,
                fill: 'start'
            }]
        },
        options: options
    });
```

My values is in range from 0 to 1.5 and i have one line at 10 or 20

Here is the pictures
[Now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi3dM.png)
[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9Fxc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options, switching to the new beta version where it is default or implement it yourself in the following way

```
options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return calculateNormalValueFromScientetific(value);
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Documentation of it: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats

Comment: I`ve already had this, it worked few times and then not. About beta version, is it the last version on their github?

Comment: There beta is the current master branch, if you want to use the beta you can put @next after the package name to use the latest beta

Answer (score 0):

My solution: update to 3 beta 8 version. Still don`t know why it didn't work previously.